# seq(...) argument "length.out" vs. "length"

Tags: r

everyone.
I just started learning r programming with swirl.

I just learned `seq`.
On the actual practice, the argument for setting a desired length of the sequence was noted as `length` . Yet, when I read the help document relating to `seq`, I found that `length.out` is the argument noted with the same definition. And there were no mentioning of `length` as an argument within `seq`.

I know this is very elementary for most of you, but I wanted to know why that was different on the swirl module.

I googled the title of this posting to see if anyone has asked the same question. But I wasn't able to find anything on it.

Thank you so much for reading and I hope to hear from someone soon.

Comment: Please see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching

Comment: @Henrik I wasn't aware that my question was directly related to partial matching due to my lack of knowledge in R. The answer was based on a different question which dealt with argument-matching. I'll check the materials you recommended. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct upon looking at `?seq` - the argument is actually named `length.out`. R allows you to use "partial matching". This means you can abbreviate names of arguments:

```
seq(f = 1, b = 5, leng = 10)
# [1]  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46

seq(from = 1, by = 2, length.out = 10)
# [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```